# What is the best way for SPAs to communicate data to node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, web-applications, single-page-application

I am a Fullstack web-developer which also wants to create SPAs (single-page-applications). So I was wondering what is the best way for the client (browser for example) to communicate data with the server without the page reloading or having multiple pages for different parts of the website? I want to create dynamic websites as well as use that knowledge for mobile web apps later on. And instead of the old  way of sending data and returning it with a response, what could be a more dynamic and better way of doing this?

Comment: You mean like using AJAX?

Comment: Well, I've been using web-sockets but I was wondering if there is something really good I don't know about which does a similar job.

Comment: Ajax is the defacto standard. Websockets works as well. Read up on the difference between the two. Moreover, I’m seeing Angular as an answer. This is a clientside framework and it’s Completely unrelated to your question. (It uses ajax and/or websockets to communicate with the server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be reached in many ways but I would recommend you to take a look to websocket protocol. If you want to build it from scratch, [socketio](http://socket.io) could be a good option. If you want build it with a framework, there are some of them that use websocket, for example [feather.js](https://feathersjs.com/), for reactive rest apis, or [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/), that is more powerful and complex.

Comment: Thank you, so the WebSocket protocol is the way to go? I have been using socket.io so I did get the basic understanding. Do I conclude that the WebSocket protocol is the best one and the one I should continue using only?

Comment: No, it depends on what are you building. But as websocket let open a full duplex connection, it will allow server to send data back without asking for it, like a notification or a chat message, without techniques like long poolling. If you only want the client sending message to server and respond to that message, you don't really need it - but it is still helpful. You could go with ajax for this kind of behaviour, through http protocol.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you use Angular 6 where you will be able to use component-based application, each page or part of the page is denoted by a component, you can then bootstrap your app to integrate all components for dynamically built app, it does not require page loading (post-back loading). [angular 6](http://angular.io)

Comment: Thank you, but when it comes to getting data from a database for example I would need to somehow send a request to the server and then get a response. With angular how would I do this without having the page to reload and still keeping it dynamic?

Comment: Why on earth you have to reload the web page on angular??? Fetch the data and render on appropriate position.

Comment: you never have to reload the page in angular 6 , you can go through the docs here : https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 @Valchy , Shams Nahid : I did not mention it is required to reload the page. it is self-evident when it comes to using Angular 6

Comment: @ShamsNahid : Here is the live example  : https://yjpebbxqbeba.angular.stackblitz.io/dashboard

Comment: Guys, I think maybe I wasn't clear enough on my question... Yes, I am using angular, but what I am trying to figure out here is the best way to communicate data (between the browser and the server, - its a node js operated server) again and again without the page reloading. Of course, that angular allows dynamic change instantly when a variable is changed for example but what I want here the best way of getting that data over and over again without having request response and having the page to reload :D @AmadoSaladino